# Difference between "$i" and :$("$i") in Julia DataFrame

Tags: julia

When `i=1`, both `println(typeof("$i"))` and `println(typeof(:($("$i"))))` give `String`, and both `println("$i")` and `println(:($("$i")))` give `1`. However, the following code

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame()
i = 1
df.:($("$i")) = [0.0]
println(df)
```

works, but the following code

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame()
i = 1
df."$i" = [0.0]
println(df)
```

does not work. What is wrong with the latter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend you to rely on the either syntax. These are corner cases of Julia parser.

The fact that:

```
df.:($("$i")) = [0.0]
```

works is most likely not a conscious design decision on Julia parser side. Note that:

```
df.:($("$i"))
```

fails.

As it is explained in https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/getting_started/:

> Note that in the forms `df."col"` and `:var"col"` variable interpolation into a string using `$` does not work.

If you want to use interpolation either directly call `setproperty!` and `getproperty` or use `getindex`/`setindex!`, in this case:

```
df[!, "$i"] = [0.0]
```